# In the group $U(50)$, how would you find the order of the group element $3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

In the group $U(50)$ under multiplication modulo $50$, how would you find the order of the group element $3 \in U(50)$. I'm trying to figure out how to apply the following corollary to find the order of group element $3$.

> Let $|a|=n$. Then $\langle a\rangle =\langle a^{j}\rangle $ if and only if $\gcd(n, j)= 1$, and$|a|=|\langle a^{j}\rangle |$ if and only if $\gcd(n, j)=1.$

Comment: I don't see how that corollary is relevant to determining the order of 3 in $U(50)$.  Perhaps you might consider a different approach?

Comment: Initially, I thought that the corollary could determine the order of $3$ in $U(50)$, but then I realized that the only way I could find the order would be to compute the powers of $3$.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use this instead. (Thm 4.1 corollary 1 found in *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* by Gallian, Joseph, 8th Edition)

"For any group element $a$, $|a|=|\langle a\rangle|$."

In this case $|\langle 3\rangle |$ is 20, so $|3|$ is also 20.

Answer (score 1):

Keep multiplying $3$ by itself until you get $1$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/999318)

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco How does this not provide an answer to the question? The question asks how to compute the order of 3 in the multiplicative group mod 50. The answer is to keep multiplying it by itself until one reaches $1$.